# Should we remove the custom-widgets tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are several dozen questions using this tag.  Some deal with a variety of different GUI libraries, some deal with javascript libraries, some deal with changing the appearance of wordpress.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-widgets

It doesn't seem like a very useful tag, especially considering it's being used to refer to several different, unrelated things.  The Qt and other GUI library usage don't really make much sense, since pretty much everything is a "custom widget".

The wordpress usage seems like the best usage of the tag, though "wordpress-widget" seems like a better tag to me.